# Remove ExtJS Styling

Tags: javascript, extjs, styling

I need to remove styling fron HTML I insert into a fieldset/panel.  I recall reading somewhere (in one of the newer releases) that ExtJS provides this features, but I need it for an older release.  Has anybody implemented this capability/feature - specifically for ExtJS - or have a suggestion that will work for ExtJS?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to override the default inherited styles like the reset CSS that is applied globally?  There's nothing built-in for that -- you basically have to write whatever override CSS you need and apply it after the Ext stylesheets.  Make sure that you give your parent panel an id or cls, then write your override rules to be relative to that id/cls.  I know it's a bit of a pain, but that's what you have to do.

Comment: Have you seen this as a feature in a newer release of ExtJS?  I saw it somewhere...

Comment: According to the roadmap (http://www.extjs.com/products/extjs/roadmap.php) CSS scoping was added in 3.0, but I have not personally verified that since I'm not actively using 3.x at this time.  For versions <3.0, you'd have to do as I described above.

Comment: Right; I was hoping to take a peek at the code in 3.x - maybe borrow the implementation.  Thanks.